# Setting values in DataFrames using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a configuration where it would be extremely useful to modify value of a dataframe using a combination of loc and iloc.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,6],[2,5],[2,7]],columns=['A','B'])
```

Basically in the dataframe above, I would like to take only the column that are equal to something (i.e. A = 2). which would give :

```
   A  B
3  2  6
4  2  5
5  2  7
```

And then modify the value of B of the second index (which is actually the index 4 in this case)
I can access to the value I want using this command :

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 2,'B'].iat[1]
```

(or .iloc instead of .iat, but I heard that for changing a lot of single row, iat is faster)

It yields me : 5

However I cannot seems to be able to modify it using the same command :

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 2,'B'].iat[1] = 0
```

It gives me :

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4
3  2  6
4  2  5
5  2  7
```

I would like to get this :

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4
3  2  6
4  2  0
5  2  7
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should not chain `.loc` and `.iloc` (`iat`,`at`)

```
df.loc[df.index[df.A==2][1],'B']=0
df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4
3  2  6
4  2  0
5  2  7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go around with `cumsum`, which counts the instances:

```
s = df['A'].eq(2)

df.loc[s & s.cumsum().eq(2), 'B'] = 0
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4
3  2  6
4  2  0
5  2  7
```